How long could the Deep Space Network remain in contact with Voyager if the antenna was double the size?
According to NASA:

The two Voyager spacecraft could remain in the range of the Deep Space Network through about 2036

Currently, the DSN (Deep Space Network)'s largest antenna is 70 meters in diameter. What if NASA made an antenna like that one, except double the size, so 140 meters in diameter? How long would the two Voyager spacecraft be in the range of the the new antenna for?

Range is proportional to dish diameter.

So it would be exactly double the range? @JohnDoty

Nothing physical is exact, but essentially yes.

@PM2Ring Do you want to add that as an answer?

Relevant: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35854/how-long-could-we-communicate-with-voyager-1-2-if-power-wasnt-a-problem

@JohnDoty ... yes, area is proportional to the square of diameter but signal strength is inversely proportional to distance so the squares cancel and range is proportional to diameter. But what about diffraction due to antenna dimeter? It has a big effect on the transmitting antenna, but does it affect the receiving antenna?

@Woody Transmitting and receiving are reciprocal, so you may compute the antenna gain either from beamwidth (diffraction) or collecting area and get the same answer.

Whilst the largest single dish is 70m, the DSN regularly makes use of arraying the 34m dishes to communicate to the voyager. (https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/52412/tradeoffs-between-using-two-34-m-and-one-70-m-deep-space-network-dish) So the 70m dish diameter isn't necessarily the limit of the existing DSN infrastructure.

@user1937198 I'd imagine there is a point where the 34m dishes dont work but the 70m dishes do...otherwise they wouldn't say they lose contact at 2036

From a quick research, the main constraint seems to be the DSS-43 antenna. Whilst the arraying can be used for downlink, only the DSS-43 70m antenna can currently be used for uplink.

As John Doty mentions in a comment, the range is approximately proportional to the dish diameter. That's because of the inverse square law.
The Voyagers are in hyperbolic trajectories. Their distance from the Sun is always increasing, but their speeds are decreasing as they climb out of the Sun's gravitational well, trading kinetic energy for potential energy.
As I said on Astronomy.SE in my answer to Voyager spacecraft distance from Earth

The current speeds of Voyager 1 and 2 relative to the Sun are roughly 17 km/s and 15 km/s, respectively. Earth's orbital speed is around 30 km/s, so there are periods each year when the Voyagers have negative speed relative to Earth.

In 2036, the distance from Earth to the Voyagers will be around 30 billion km and 26 billion km. Here are some Horizons plots, using the TDB timescale, with a 10 day timestep.


Let's assume that the maximum range with the 70 metre DSN dishes is 30 billion km.
The distance to Voyager1 in 2092 is ~60 billion km.

Voyager2 will be ~56 billion km at 2100. No trajectory data is available after that time.

It's a bit tricky extrapolating that wiggly graph beyond 2100. But from the Sun-Voyager2 distance graph (timestep = 60 days), it looks like Voyager2 would reach 60 billion km in 2109 or 2110.


Note that the half-life of plutonium-238 is 87.7 years, and RTG thermocouples lose efficiency over time. So the Voyagers won't have much power by then.

Incidentally, when you're as far away as the Voyagers, the Earth has a very small angular separation from the Sun. So when the Voyager receivers are picking up signals from Earth they're also getting radio noise from the Sun. In 2036, the Earth is generally less than half a degree from the Sun, from the Voyager's POV. That's about the same as the angular diameter of the Sun as seen from Earth.
Here are some Horizons plots of the ecliptic longitude and latitude of the Sun & Earth, as seen by the Voyagers, with a 5 day timestep. The Sun positions are the orange lines in the middle of the plots.



Thank you. I wonder if the Voyagers could even survive that long, but that's for another question :)

@Starship Yep. I assume they'll run out of hydrazine before then. Also the thrusters have experienced a bit of wear & tear and blockages over the decades. Hydrazine isn't exactly a gentle chemical.

There's also a question of the value of the data by that point.  Once it's well into the interstellar medium I'm not sure how much value there is to the ongoing measurements with its limited instrument package.

We shouldn't forget that when you increase the dish size, you potentially need to improve your pointing accuracy. The increased gain comes at the cost of a tighter focus.

@Starship I added a couple more plots you may find interesting.

Which unit was used for latitude and longitude?

@Uwe From https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/manual.html#obsquan
"31. Observer ecliptic longitude & latitude For non-Earth sites, the Earth ecliptic at reference-frame standard epoch is used (J2000). Units: DEGREES". But it's observer-centred, so it's actually using a plane parallel to the J2000 ecliptic passing through the observer.

The longitude & latitude plotting script can be found in https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/57281/16685 also see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/55620/16685
